# Wordpress php echo issue

Tags: php, wordpress, strip-tags

Im trying to filter out all of the tags inside a post in wordpress using strip_tags(). I set it up like this:

```
<?php
// The Query
echo date ("Y");
query_posts( 'p=10' );
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$footertext = the_content(); 
echo strip_tags($footertext);
endwhile;
// Reset Query
?>
```

This doesn't seem to strip out the tags they way I expected.

Comment: What way did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `the_content()` to `get_the_content()`.

`the_content()` is used to directly output the contents whereas `get_the_content` returns contents to be stored in variable for further processing.

```
$footertext = get_the_content();
```

Comment: Can I use this inside the loop?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you can try it.